# How to prevent calling onDestroy() method when power button is clicked on device below API level 13?

Tags: android

I am developing an android app where my activity is in `Landscape` mode. When I am clicking on power button its automatically calling onDestroy() method .

I want to prevent calling the onDestroy() method. I searched on internet and found that I have to declare

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

in manifest.xml file as well as have to override following method in my activity.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

but `screenSize` is only supported above API 13. Is there any way which can solve my problem ? I know a lot of same type of questions were asked earlier , but I couldn't found a concrete answer.

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: @kumar I just want to prevent calling automatic call of onDestroy() method  when I click on sleep button.

Comment: @kumar What I found is because my activity is in Landscape mode , when it goes to sleep by default it's going to portrait mode, that's why its calling onDestroy() method.

Comment: I think you need to handle the state and embrace onDestroy() being called instead of working against it. Does not sound very Android'ish.

Comment: android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden". This will solve. And one important thing is  use "layout" folder for landscape layout files don't use "layout-land" as folder name. Try this and let me know.

Comment: @Kumar It's not working.

Comment: @Kunu -Try to rebuild the app freshly once and see. I had the same problem solved by following the above told way.

Comment: If you are getting exception when tapped on power key then add on more folder "layout-port" and copy the same layout to this folder. Which will avoid exception.